# I write a jquery animation,but it was too long ,how to use array[i] to make this short?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

the function is very simple, there are 4 elements, the function just addClass to the first one and removeClass when the animation ended,and the same thing the the element 2, element 3 and element 4 and loop...
but this was too long ,is there any way to use array[i] or anything else to instead of the long sentence

```
$(document).ready(function(){
setInterval(function(){
    $(".reason_item1>.front").addClass("reason_item1_move").one('animationend',function(){
        $(this).removeClass("reason_item1_move");
        $(".reason_item2>.front").addClass("reason_item2_move").one('animationend',function(){
            $(this).removeClass("reason_item2_move");
                $(".reason_item3>.front").addClass("reason_item3_move").one('animationend',function(){
                $(this).removeClass("reason_item3_move");
                    $(".reason_item4>.front").addClass("reason_item4_move").one('animationend',function(){
                    $(this).removeClass("reason_item4_move");
                })
            })
        })
    })
},20000);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a recursive loop:

```
function nxt(i) {
    $(".reason_item"+i+">.front").addClass("reason_item"+i+"_move").one('animationend',function(){
        $(this).removeClass("reason_item+i+_move");
        if (i+1 > 4) {
            return;
        }
        next(i+1);
    });
}

setInterval(nxt,20000);;
```